# Why are we writing integer instead of int in enumeration?

Tags: java, enumeration

This question is different according to situation, the question for which you marked my question as duplicate doesn't completely answer my question.

import java.util.Enumeration;
import java.util.Vector;

```
public class EnumerationDemo {
 
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Vector vector = new Vector();
        for (int item = 1; item <= 5; item++) {
            vector.addElement(item);
        }
        System.out.println(vector);
        Enumeration enumeration = vector.elements();
        while (enumeration.hasMoreElements()) {
            Integer integer = (Integer) enumeration.nextElement();
            System.out.println(integer);
        }
    }
}
```

Why are we writing `integer` instead of `int` in enumeration?

Comment: Why are you using a `Vector`? This code also appears to predate generics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are allowed to write `int` instead of `Integer`, like this:

```
int integer = (Integer) enumeration.nextElement();
```

This compiles and runs on Java version 5 or later due to autoboxing/unboxing ([demo](http://ideone.com/lN89t9)).

The reason you need to do a cast to `Integer`, not `int`, is that Java treats primitive types separately from `Object`-derived reference types, making it impossible to store primitives in standard Java collections without wrapping them in their `Object`-derived equivalent.